# How do I combine elements from a list in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, list, merge, concatenation

I have a list `sims` in R that contains 404 elements. Each element of the list is itself a list with a length of 24. Each of these lists has the same column names, namely `L1` to `L24`.

So `sims[[1]]$L1` looks as follows:

```
$L1
 [1] "1" "1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "1"
[22] "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0"
[43] "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0"
```

For each internal list, the values are always character data and there are always the same number of character values. So `sims[[1]]$L1`...`sims[[1]]$L24` all have 55 characters as in the above example. But `sims[[4]]$L1`...`sims[[4]]$L24` has only one character value.

I am trying to concatenate the internal lists. Specifically, I want to take every four internal lists of `sims` (i.e., sims[[1]] through sims[[4]], sims[[4]] through sims[[8]], sims[[8]] through sims[[12]], etc.) and concatenate them.

`sims[[2]]$L1` looks as follows:

```
$L1
 [1] "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "2" "2" "0" "2" "0" "1" "1" "2" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1"
```

`sims[[3]]$L1` looks as follows:

```
$L1
 [1] "1" "0" "3" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2"
```

`sims[[4]]$L1` looks as follows:

```
$L1
"2"
```

So what I want is to concatenate `sims[[1]]` to `sims[[4]]` (each of which contains 24 columns) so that the `L1` have all of the above character values:

```
"1" "1" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "1"
"0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0"
"1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "1" "1" "0" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0" "1" "2" "2" "0" "2" "0" "1" "1" "2" "1" "0" "0" "0" "1" "1" "0" "3" "1" "2" "2" "1" "2" "1" "2" "2"
```

This concatenation process would occur for each of the 24 columns `L1` through `L24`.

I then want to iterate this contatenation process for `sims[[5]]` through `sims[[8]]` and `sims[[9]]` through `sims[[12]]`, all the way through to `sims[[404]]` in sets of four. I have tried many different things with `merge`, but have not even come close to a solution. How do I do this in R?

**EDIT**

Here is a simplified version of the list `sims`, which has 8 internal lists. Each of these internal lists has 3 columns, `L1`, `L2`, and `L3`. The values of each internal list are character data and the number of character values varies.

```
sims[[1]]$L1 "0" "1" "0"
sims[[1]]$L2 "1" "0" "0"
sims[[1]]$L3 "1" "?" "0"
```

```
sims[[2]]$L1 "0" "1"
sims[[2]]$L2 "2" "0"
sims[[2]]$L3 "3" "3"
```

```
sims[[3]]$L1 "0" 
sims[[3]]$L2 "2" 
sims[[3]]$L3 "1"
```

```
sims[[4]]$L1 "0" "1" 
sims[[4]]$L2 "1" "1"
sims[[4]]$L3 "3" "2"
```

```
sims[[5]]$L1 "1" "1" "1"
sims[[5]]$L2 "1" "2" "2"
sims[[5]]$L3 "3" "1" "2"
```

```
sims[[6]]$L1 "0"
sims[[6]]$L2 "1"
sims[[6]]$L3 "3"
```

```
sims[[7]]$L1 "0" "0" "0"
sims[[7]]$L2 "1" "2" "2"
sims[[7]]$L3 "3" "0" "1"
```

```
sims[[8]]$L1 "0" 
sims[[8]]$L2 "1"
sims[[8]]$L3 "1"
```

I want to concatenate the values of `sims[[1]]` through `sims[[4]]` and `sims[[5]]` through `sims[[8]]` to produce the following list:

```
sims[[1]]$L1 "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1"
sims[[1]]$L2 "1" "0" "0" "2" "0" "2" "1" "1"
sims[[1]]$L3 "1" "?" "0" "3" "3" "1" "3" "2"

sims[[2]]$L1 "1" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"
sims[[2]]$L2 "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1"
sims[[2]]$L3 "3" "1" "2" "3" "3" "0" "1" "1"
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're needing, but it's a little unclear with the sample data. Can you use `list` (concoct smaller, similar data) or `dput` (give us the real version of your list) to clear up my confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Base R:

```
f <- rep(seq_along(sims), each=4, length=length(sims))
lapply(split(sims, f), \(x)do.call(Map, c(c, x))) 

$`1`
$`1`$L1
[1] "0" "1" "0" "0" "1" "0" "0" "1"

$`1`$L2
[1] "1" "0" "0" "2" "0" "2" "1" "1"

$`1`$L3
[1] "1" "?" "0" "3" "3" "1" "3" "2"


$`2`
$`2`$L1
[1] "1" "1" "1" "0" "0" "0" "0" "0"

$`2`$L2
[1] "1" "2" "2" "1" "1" "2" "2" "1"

$`2`$L3
[1] "3" "1" "2" "3" "3" "0" "1" "1"
```

---

```
sims <- list(list(L1 = c("0", "1", "0"), L2 = c("1", "0", "0"), L3 = c("1", 
"?", "0")), list(L1 = c("0", "1"), L2 = c("2", "0"), L3 = c("3", 
"3")), list(L1 = "0", L2 = "2", L3 = "1"), list(L1 = c("0", "1"
), L2 = c("1", "1"), L3 = c("3", "2")), list(L1 = c("1", "1", 
"1"), L2 = c("1", "2", "2"), L3 = c("3", "1", "2")), list(L1 = "0", 
    L2 = "1", L3 = "3"), list(L1 = c("0", "0", "0"), L2 = c("1", 
"2", "2"), L3 = c("3", "0", "1")), list(L1 = "0", L2 = "1", L3 = "1"))
```